# How to call Loopback4 controller's method from another controller

Tags: javascript, server, loopbackjs, loopback

I have a loopback 4 controller with a function that I don't want to expose via HTTP. I would like to be able to call the function from another controller.

How can I do this? Is there any way of injecting a controller in another controller?
(I 'm able to inject repositories in controllers, but not controllers in other controllers).

Answer (score 5):

You have to first import repository of another controller e.g.

```
import { MemberRepository, EmailTemplateRepository } from '../repositories';
```

then you have to inject it in constructor like this:-

```
@repository(EmailTemplateRepository) public emailTemplateRepository: EmailTemplateRepository,
```

then after you can use any function of controller like this:-

```
const template = await this.emailTemplateRepository.findOne({
  where: {
    slug: 'user-password-reset',
    status: 1
  }
});
```

Comment: This is the right approach to do this. Controllers are supposed to be independent of each other. If you don't want to expose the API, then you should not have a controller at all. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/3028

```
@inject(‘controllers.AnotherController’) c: AnotherController
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out how to make this work.  You have to import the @repository component where the rest of the other import statements are, like so:

import { repository } from '@loopback/repository';

Adding this, will allow for, @repository(EmailTemplateRepository) public emailTemplateRepository: EmailTemplateRepository, to work.