# How to call another Loopback4 Controller from another Controller?

Tags: loopback4

I've read this question/answer [How to call Loopback4 controller's method from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408784/how-to-call-loopback4-controllers-method-from-another-controller) HOWEVER, my use case is slightly different.

Unlike that answer above, I DO need my API functions to be accessible via http (and I also couldn't get even get the answer in the link above to work).

**My Use Case**
I need for my Main Controller to go and get all Locations via the iciService (which is all good and working) BUT then I need to insert all of that Locations data into another datasource (mongoDB), I believe by importing my Locations Controller, right?  But how exactly is what I'm not sure on.

I've research this but I'm unclear.  I'm not a strong programmer.

Here's my **Main Controller** code:

```
import { inject } from '@loopback/context';
import { iciService } from '../services/ici.service';
import { get, param } from '@loopback/rest';

export class iciController {
  constructor(
    @inject('services.ici')
    private iciService: iciService
  ) {}

  @get('/locations')
  getall() {
    return this.iciService.getLocations();
  }
}
```

And here's the **Locations controller** that I need to link out to.

```
import {
  Count,
  CountSchema,
  Filter,
  FilterExcludingWhere,
  repository,
  Where,
} from '@loopback/repository';
import {
  post,
  param,
  get,
  getModelSchemaRef,
  patch,
  put,
  del,
  requestBody,
} from '@loopback/rest';
import {Location} from '../models';
import {LocationRepository} from '../repositories';

export class LocationController {
  constructor(
    @repository(LocationRepository)
    public locationRepository : LocationRepository,
  ) {}

  @post('/locations', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Location model instance',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: getModelSchemaRef(Location)}},
      },
    },
  })
  async create(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Location, {
            title: 'NewLocation',

          }),
        },
      },
    })
    location: Location,
  ): Promise<Location> {
    return this.locationRepository.create(location);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call Loopback4 controller's method from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408784/how-to-call-loopback4-controllers-method-from-another-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Ok after much research on Github repos of other Loopback4 apps, I figured out to get the other Stackoverflow to work ([How to call Loopback4 controller's method from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408784/how-to-call-loopback4-controllers-method-from-another-controller)).

Although my fix doesn't technically call another Controller, I am able to access the Repository that the Controller (Locations) uses.

So, I just had to add the import for the @repository at the top of my **Main Controller**, like so:

import { repository } from '@loopback/repository';

So my **Main Controller** page looks like:

```
import { inject } from '@loopback/context';
import { repository } from '@loopback/repository';
import { iciService } from '../services/ici.service';
import { get, param } from '@loopback/rest';

export class iciController {
  constructor(
    @inject('services.ici')
    private iciService: iciService,

    @repository(JobRepository)
    private jobRepository: JobRepository,
  ) {}

  @get('/locations')
  getall() {

    //NOW YOU CAN ACCESS THE FUNCTIONS IN THE jobRepository
    return this.jobRepository.count();
  }
}
```